# Laravel 5.5: Send value of hidden form input to controller

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In my view, I'm getting all the available slots so a user can click the book button to book that slot. However, I just can't seem to find a way to get the **correct** value (id of the input) so I can set the status of the specific booking in the database to booked.

index.blade.php

```
@if(count($slots) > 0)
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Time</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                @foreach($slots as $slot)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$slot->date}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$slot->time}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input name="id" value="{{$slot->id}}" type="hidden"> THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO SEND
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Book</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
```

BookingsController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $booking = new Booking;
        $booking->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $booking->date_id = THIS IS WHAT I NEED;

                    DB::table('calendar')
                            ->select('id','status')
                            ->where('id', GET DATE ID)
                            ->update(['status' => 1]);          
        $booking->save();



        return redirect('/bookings')->with([
                'success' => 'Booking successful!',
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the request object to retrieve the parameters you send :

`$whatYouNeed = $request->id` (or in general `$request->WhateverYouNamedYourField`)

Edit : This is not related to hidden fields only, it works with any kind of form fields.

Comment: When I use this, I don't get the correct id of the field. E.g. if i click on the first button to book, it'll pass the very last id which will book the wrong date and leaves the first date available

Comment: You must have a form for each row, not a global form for all your rows.

Comment: I do have a form for each row. Check index.blade.php

Comment: As far as I see, you have inputs and buttons for each row, not a form. I guess your `<form method="post">` tag is a the top of your file, no ?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your earlier comment. Yes, the form tag is at the top of the file

Comment: This is why you only have the last value, basically, what is happening is that every input re-defines the value of the id, so you end up with the value of the last input. To solve that, create a form on each `<td>` that sends to the same URL, but with a different value.

Comment: You are welcome, please mark the question as answered so people can find an answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

[Request docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)

In store function you are Typehinting Request.

`store(Request  $request)`

The first **Request** is referring to the request handler. 
So if you'll put this after your.

`$booking->date_id = $request->input('id')`

Thats your answer.

You are requesting the input id from the request input

Comment: When I use this, I don't get the correct id of the field. E.g. if i click on the first button to book, it'll pass the very last id which will book the wrong date and leaves the first date available

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input)

```
 $request->all();
```

or

```
 $request->get('filedName');
```

or

```
 $request->fieldName;
```

or

```
$request->input('fieldName');
```

These are the ways of getting inputs including hidden ones

Comment: The problem I'm finding is that if I use $request->get('id'), for example, and I clicked on the very first button where id = 1, it instead passes through the very last id (in this case 28) and books that slot rather than first

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple of inputs with same name ?

Comment: Yes, in the index file I'm using the foreach to get all the available slots a user can book and with that a button is created